# provably optimal search algorithms?

Tags: complexity-theory, search-algorithms

In practical applications, search algorithms are often strengthened using heuristics. e.g., Deep Blue beat gary kasparov by searching through possible chess moves by "guiding" its search with human-chosen heuristics. **These heuristics are not proven to be the optimal heuristics.**  (they're not optimal obviously).

I am wondering however:

> Is there *some* kind of search problem (ideally a non-trivial one), where (1) there is a specific known algorithm that solves it, and (2) a proof that the algorithm is optimal in the sense that **there does not exist an algorithm that solves it faster** **in expectation**, where (3) the probability distribution for that expectation is the relevant one for that practical search problem?

I'm interested in anything related to this. If you know something that seems partially relevant, please say so.

**EDIT**: Alternatively, please suggest a different notion of "optimality" if you think it is more relevant. I am not sure how relevant my notion of optimality is.

**EDIT 2:** I'm also interested in how this question relates to the 'No free lunch' theorems in search and optimization.

Comment: In expectation over what probability distribution? Random instances often have little connection to "real life".

Comment: @DavidRicherby, edited?

Comment: Does quicksort count? If not, why?

Comment: @Apass.Jack, I'm not sure I would call quicksort a "search algorithm". Also, I don't know whether quicksort is optimal, or in what sense

Comment: Sorry, I meant to type "binary search". Does binary search count? If not, why?

Comment: @Apass.Jack, I see. It might count, but I don't know because I don't know about any proof that it is optimal. Is there a proof that the simplest form of binary search (or some other form) is optimal? Does that just mean that its asymptotic bound has the same form? (i.e. $O(log n)$ ). There could still be another algorithm with a much smaller constant term, or that is more efficient for small array's or something.

Comment: Under uniform distribution of sorted array as input and comparison mode of computation, it can be proven that binary search performs the least average number of comparisons. I am talking about the exact bound. Does binary search count then?

Comment: @Apass.Jack, That definitely sounds like the kind of thing I have in mind, though I'm not sure if the "comparison mode of computation" might be problematic. Is this a restriction on the algorithm, or on the information that the algorithm is allowed to use? In any case, if you are willing to write an answer explaining this, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Finding an optimal solution for a problem is very difficult. for example in sorting you can prove that the optimal solution with comparison is $O(n \log n)$ but may be you can find an algorithm with $O(n)$ without comparison like hashing! another good example is NP Complete problems we even can't prove they haven't polynomial algorithm. so it is very hard to find an optimal solution for deep blue and similar algorithms and proving that the algorithm is optimal is very hard too.